# Is there a convenient programatic way to create google plus test users

Tags: google-plus

Is there a convenient programatic way to create google plus test users?

I searched through most of the google plus apis provided in their dev resources portal, however did not find a decent way to create test users.

Any advice would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general use, no there isn't a programmatic way to create test accounts.

However, if you have a [Google Apps domain](http://www.google.com/intx/en/enterprise/apps/business/), you could use the [Admin SDK to create user accounts within your domain](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#create_user), which would likely suffice for most testing that you might need to do. You'd also need to make sure that Google+ was enabled for the domain. And there are some limitations, such as not being able to use the `plus.login` scope.

I realize this solution is unlikely to work for most people, but you never know.

Comment: Ah thank you, I just went over that documentation. not being able to use plus.login is a problem. I appricate the help though. Thank you.

Comment: the problem with this method is that it costs $4-5 for every new test user.. so it can add quite a bit of strain on a start-up's piggy bank, but i'm giving you a +1 anyways :)